# Ciphersaber Decryption Algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, encryption, char

I'm trying to finish a Ciphersaber decryption algorithm with C++. I have never did nothing related with encryption or decryption, so I'm a little bit lost. The algorithm is based in [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4).

After several tries, I finally got some code it seems to work, but does not show the correct input result at all. That is why I'm making this call. Is someone familiarised with this type of decryption algorithms capable of tell me what am I doing wrong?

I appreciate a lot your help! Thank you. Ask me for any doubt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Parameters {
    std::string EncryptedData;
    std::string EncryptionKey;
    int InitialVectorLength;
    int KeyLoopIterations;
    
    void LoadParameters() {
        EncryptedData = "6f 6d 0b ab f3 aa 67 19 03 15 30 ed b6 77 ca 74 e0 08 9d d0 e7 b8 85 43 56 bb 14 48 e3 7c db ef e7 f3 a8 4f 4f 5f b3 fd";
        EncryptionKey = "asdfg";
        InitialVectorLength = 10;
        KeyLoopIterations = 1;
    };
};

void RC4(int n, int r, char* k, int l, unsigned char* keystream) {
    unsigned char S [256] = { };
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++) {
        S[i]=i;
    }  

    int j=0;
    for(int ri=0; ri<r; ri++) {
        for(int i=0; i<256; i++) {
            j = (j + S[i] + k[i%l]) % 256;
            swap(S[i], S[j]);
        }
    }

    j=0;
    int ip;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        ip = (i+1) % 256;
        j = (j+S[ip]) % 256;
        swap(S[ip], S[j]);
        keystream[i] = S[(S[ip]+S[j]) % 256];
    }
};

void Decrypt(std::string m, int iv_length, std::string k, int r) {
    int n = m.length() + iv_length;
    unsigned char output[1024];

    char iv [iv_length];
    for(int i=0; i<iv_length; i++) {
        iv[i] = m[i];
    }   

    char msg_no_iv [n-iv_length];
    for(int k=0; k<n-iv_length; k++) {
        msg_no_iv[k]=m[k+iv_length];
    }  

    char kp[k.length()+iv_length];
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<k.length(); i++) {
        kp[i] = k[i];
    }

    for(unsigned int i=k.length(); i<k.length()+iv_length; i++) {
        kp[i] = iv[i-k.length()];
    }

    unsigned char keystream [256];
    RC4(n, r, kp, k.length()+iv_length, keystream);  

    for(int i=0; i<n-iv_length; i++) { 
        output[i] = msg_no_iv[i] ^ keystream[i];
    }
    
    cout << output;
};

int main()
{
    Parameters params;
    params.LoadParameters();
    
    Decrypt(params.EncryptedData, params.InitialVectorLength, params.EncryptionKey, params.KeyLoopIterations);
    
    return 0;
};
```

***EXPECTED OUTPUT:***

```
This is a test of CipherSaber.
```

> Useful links:
>
> - What CipherSaber is? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CipherSaber
> - CipherSaber Official Website: http://ciphersaber.gurus.org/
> - Some repositories that use the algorithm: https://github.com/search?q=ciphersaber&ref=opensearch

Comment: This code does not compile.

Comment: Where? To me does compile :/

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at your implementation I see that the encrypted data is on hexadecimal, and you don't convert it back.
Also, don't mix `unsigned char` with `char`.